# How could one copy union simple members with memcpy?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, std, unions, standards-compliance

I'm not quite sure about standard quotes about `memcpy` and `union` trivial members.

Consider the code:

```cpp
struct Test{
    union
    {
        void(*function_p)(void*);
        void(*function_p_c)(const void*);
    };
    Test(const Test &other)
    {
        using std::memcpy;
        memcpy(&function_p, &other.function_p, sizeof(function_p)); //?
        memcpy(&function_p_c, &other.function_p_c, sizeof(function_p_c)); //??
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Test t1; t1.function_p = NULL; //let it be NULL for c++98 sake
    Test t2(t1); // is it safe? does this set new active member of union?

    return 0;
}
```

So the one question leads to another:

- is code above safe? or is it UB with second/first `memcpy` depending on which `union` member user have touched? is it overkill to call `memcpy` for both members?
- if it is not safe then how could I implement copy constructor without some flag-of-active-union-member?

Comment: Note: I just added the `language-lawyer` tag, which is customary for this kind of question. Since there's a max of five tags, I picked `std` to remove for that.

Comment: Why? Why not just use `=`?

Comment: With named union member, you might do one `memcpy`.

Comment: Or create two classes `TestA` and `TestB`, one with a member `function_p` and the other one with `function_p_c` instead. - You say that you want to do it "without some flag-of-active-union-member". If you don't have that kind of flag, how are you going to *use* the correct funtion pointer at other places in the class?

Comment: @JimmyB that's the trick, the class itself is a bit more complicated. Example piece shows just the problem.

Comment: @Jarod42 would it be standard- conforming to memcpy union as a whole class member?

Comment: depends on type inside union, but in your case, yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing with two memcpy is undefined behavior.

> The [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) is only as big as necessary to hold its largest data member.
>   The other data members are allocated in the same bytes as part of that
>   largest member. The details of that allocation are
>   implementation-defined, **and it's undefined behavior to read from the
>   member of the union that wasn't most recently written.** Many compilers
>   implement, as a non-standard language extension, the ability to read
>   inactive members of a union.

`other` has only `function_p` as active and the second memcopy triggers undefined behavior.

Comment: Is memcpy'ed member considered "written"?

Comment: @AlexanderG. Seems there's an open debate on the subject. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39763548/10933809. You need a bookkeeping mechanism to know the  active type or initialize one member first(so make it active) and then memcpy

Comment: @AlexanderG. You may follow Jarod42 comment. Or if C++17 is an option use std::variant instead of union.

Answer (score -2):

Since both union members occupy the same space in memory, the second memcpy will overwrite the first.

Comment: @Oblivion I did not downvote, but this answer does not answer any of the questions OP asked.

Comment: @mch I agree it doesn't answer. But I believe leaving comment helps to improve posts