# Using negative array index to access preceeding member

Tags: c++, arrays, pointer-aliasing

I'd like to use a negative array index to access the same-type member that immediately precedes that array in a struct.

Consider this type of code:

```
union hello {
    int a[2];
    struct { int b0; int b1[1]; };
};
```

I want to use `b1[-1]` to access `b0`.

When I try to do this, clang and gcc seem to understand exactly what I want.

```
extern const int test = hello{{42, 1337}}.b1[-1];
```

This correctly determines at compile time that `test` is really `42`.

Unfortunately, clang produces a warning that `-1` is not in bound. Gcc does too if I change `const` to `constexpr`.

What is the correct way to write this type of code?

Here are the ways I already know but don't like:

- Use `a[]` with 1-based indexing.
- Make `b1` a pointer that points to `a[1]`.

Comment: Presumably, you don't get the warning when accessing `c1 [i - 1]` and `i` happens to be zero, so, happy days,

Comment: I do if it happens during evaluation of a `constexpr` function. Anyway, this question is about the "correct" way to write this, rather than just what works.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have variables {c<sub>0</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>3</sub>,...}, and sometimes you want to treat them as an array [c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>3</sub>,...], an at other times as an array [c<sub>0</sub>, c<sub>1</sub>, c<sub>2</sub>, c<sub>3</sub>,...].

(I'm not sure I understand *why* you want to do this, but never mind.)

Here's one solution:

```
int A[5];
int *B = A+1;
A[0] = c0;
A[1] = c1;
A[2] = c2;
....
```

Now you can iterate over A[i] if you want to include c<sub>0</sub>, and over B[i] if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to do this, clang and gcc seem to understand exactly what I want

Yes, but they also generate some diagnostic, if asked (gcc):

```
prog.cc:6:33: warning: ISO C++ prohibits anonymous structs [-Wpedantic]
     struct { int b0; int b1[1]; };
```

Also, accessing `b1` which is not the active member of the union (`a` is the initialized one) is undefined behavior.

You could instead write a class which encapsulates the data and the wanted access logic:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<size_t Dim>
class Hello
{
    std::array<int, Dim> data_;
public:
    template<class... ArgType>
    constexpr Hello(ArgType... args) : data_{args...} {};

    constexpr int first()       const noexcept { return data_[0]; }

    constexpr int one_based(int i) const { return data_.at(i + 1); }
    constexpr int zero_based(int i) const { return data_.at(i); }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Hello<2> hi {42, 1337};

    static_assert(hi.first() == 42);

    static_assert(hi.one_based(-1) == 42);
    static_assert(hi.one_based(0) == 1337);

    static_assert(hi.zero_based(0) == 42);
    static_assert(hi.zero_based(1) == 1337);

    std::cout << "So far, so good...\n";
}
```

Comment: "Also, accessing `b1` which is not the active member of the union (`a` is the initialized one) is undefined behavior." Is this true despite the common initial subsequence rule?

Comment: @Filipp I'd say so, but I'm not a language lawyer. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388208/active-member-of-an-union-uniform-initialization-and-constructors

Comment: @Filipp It's also one of errors emitted if you try to declare `test` as `constexpr`, for what it's worth: https://wandbox.org/permlink/3aaCWLcXnGaKfgt1