# Assigning std::function inside union crashes program

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, unions, std-function

I wrote the following class which stores either a fixed value (`constant`) or a function to get a value (`get`).

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicValue {
    private:
    bool isConstant;
    union {
        T constant;
        std::function<T()> get;
    };
    void copy(const DynamicValue& value) {
        isConstant = value.isConstant;
        if (isConstant) {
            constant = value.constant;
        } else {
            std::cout << "won't overcome next line" << std::endl;
            get = value.get;
            std::cout << "why!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    public:
    DynamicValue(const T& constant) : isConstant(true), constant(constant){};
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>>
    DynamicValue(F&& get) : isConstant(false), get(std::forward<F>(get)) {}
    DynamicValue(const T* pointer) : DynamicValue([pointer]() { return *pointer; }) {}
    DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& value) { copy(value); }
    ~DynamicValue() {}
    DynamicValue& operator=(const DynamicValue& value) {
        copy(value);
        return *this;
    }
    operator T() { return isConstant ? constant : get(); }
};
```

I also wrote the following dummy class to showcase the issue I've encountered:

```
class Object {
    private:
    DynamicValue<int> num;
    
    public:
    Object(DynamicValue<int> num) : num(num) {}
};
```

The problem is when I try to initialize an `Object` with a function (by doing `Object b([] { return 1; });` for example) the program crashes. I've narrowed down the crash to the `get = value.get;` line inside the copy function. I've also noticed that the crash no longer happens if I move `get` outside the union.

You can try a live example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qEqYzx).

Why is this happening and how can I fix it (keeping `get` inside the union)?

Comment: Unions with object having a constructor is always going to be tricky. You must explicitly construct such objects.

Comment: fwiw, `std::variant` is the "new union".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what do you mean by explicitly construct?

Comment: he means that the receiving member `get` has not been properly constructed. changing the line to `auto get = value.get` will avoid the crash.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah but it won't actually achieve anything either

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings it was an attempt to clarify the cause of the problem since the OP did not seem to understand which object was not in a valid state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor for `DynamicValue` does not initialize the `get` member, causing the assignment in `copy` to fail. Adding an initialization for `get`

```
DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& value) : get() { copy(value); }
```

resolves the crash but has other issues. See version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/8Yzqj7)

Going in this direction is problematic, so you should consider changing your approach to using `std::variant`.

```
template <typename T>
class DynamicValue {
    private:
    std::variant<T, std::function<T()>> value;
    void copy(const DynamicValue& other) {
        value = other.value;
    }

    public:
    DynamicValue(const T& constant) : value(constant){};
    template <typename F, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>>>
    DynamicValue(F&& get) : value(std::forward<F>(get)) {}
    DynamicValue(const T* pointer) : DynamicValue([pointer]() { return *pointer; }) {}
    DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& value) { copy(value); }
    ~DynamicValue() {}
    DynamicValue& operator=(const DynamicValue& value) {
        copy(value);
        return *this;
    }
    operator T() { return value.index() == 0 ? std::get<0>(value) : std::get<1>(value)(); }
};
```

See working version [here](https://godbolt.org/z/onYWEr)

Comment: Looks sloppy. What if `value` has `isConstant == true`? Then `get` will be overwritten ungracefully.

Comment: And, in fact, doing such a thing will have undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is really tricky to get right with non-POD stuff in C++, which is precisely why we have `std::variant` to use instead.

Answer (score 3):

In order to [change the active member of a union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388208/active-member-of-an-union-uniform-initialization-and-constructors) to/from a non-trivial type, you must [placement new construct it / call its destructor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#general-7):

```
void copy(const DynamicValue& value) noexcept {
    if (isConstant && value.isConstant) {
        constant = value.constant;
    } else if (!isConstant && !value.isConstant) {
        get = value.get;
    } else if (value.isConstant) {
        get.~function();
        new (&constant) T(value.constant);
    } else {
        constant.~T();
        new (&get) std::function<T()>(value.get);
    }
    isConstant = value.isConstant;
}
```

Note that here `copy` is `noexcept` since there is no way to recover if the placement new fails. If you want to avoid this, you would need to add a valueless-by-exception state to your class, where it can be destructed but no other operations are valid.

In addition, since a precondition of `copy` is that your object is in a valid state, your copy constructor must first initialize itself to the `constant` state:

```
DynamicValue(const DynamicValue& value) : DynamicValue(T{}) { copy(value); }
```

Note that this assumes that `T` is default constructible. Alternatively, you could initialize to the `get` state, but this is likely to be less efficient, especially if `T` is trivial.

And finally to prevent leaks you should ensure your destructor puts the union in a trivial state:

```
~DynamicValue() {
    if (isConstant)
        constant.~T();
    else
        get.~function();
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/eeKrTc).

Comment: This will still fail if `T` is a type with a non-trivial ctor/dtor.  Better to just use `std::variant` which does all the work for you.

Comment: @ChrisDodd good point, updated. I think it's worth knowing how to implement a simple tagged union, even if only to know what the tradeoffs are in choosing to use the standard variant instead.

Comment: @ChrisDodd updated to deal with non-trivial `T`. It's not an excessive amount of work, especially if you're prepared to compromise on things like strong exception safety guarantees.